# Throwing exception from ServiceActivator vs. Filter behaves differently

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In our application we have error handling mechanism, where we throw runtime exceptions on an error. I noticed a strange behavior and I want to understand the mechanism underlying this one

1) Situation 1: Exception thrown from ServiceActivator is converted to MessageHandlingException

When an error occurs in a ServiceActivator, we throw an exception. The message we get on ErrorChannel has PayLoad as `org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException` and actual exception thrown as  `cause`

2) Situation 2: Exception thrown from Filter is not masked with MessageHandlingException

When an error occurs in Filter, and we throw exception, then PayLoad is actual exception, and is not masked with `org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException`

I have a few questions:

- Why exception throwing from ServiceActivator behaves differently than in Filter
- Are there some "best practices" around error handling in Spring-integration projects, while utilizing the errorChannel and related infrastructure

**Update 1:**

Filter extends AbstractFileListFilter which is part of a filter chain- a custom CompositeFileFilter which implements FileListFilter

CompositeFileFilter is being used by a file:inbound-channel-adapter and which passes the output to a Channel declared below:

```
<int:channel
  id="channelForFilesComingIn"
  datatype="java.io.File"
>
   <int:dispatcher task-executor="dispatchExecutor" />
</int:channel>
```

**Update 2:**

Whet we are trying to do is read files from filesystem and process them. In file reading part, using `file:inbound-channel-adapter` with a CompositeFilter which filters files which are not completely uploaded or don't meet naming standards.

After all filters pass, file is handed over to a ServiceActivator for processing

In any of above (Filter chain or Service) , if there is an error condition, it has to be reported to DB and by email. For achieving this we are throwing ApplicationException which are caught by errorChannel, and passed to specialized channels.

Comment: What version of Spring Integration are you using? I just ran a test, throwing an exception from a filter, and received the MessageHandlingException as expected. Please provide more details, including configuration.

Comment: I am using 2.1.4. I noticed this behavior in a debugging session. I am attaching more details to question.

Comment: I thought you were talking about the <filter/> element, considering you are comparing it to <service-activator/>. The file list filter is used in a MessageSource it is not a component invoked directly. Perhaps you can share more information about exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Added more details, not sure if they help you. Let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make it clear, a `MessageHandlingException` is thrown (wraps user exception) when a Message HANDLER fails - a message handler is something that HANDLES a message.

If an exception is thrown in the `MessageSource`, there is no message yet so a `MessageHandlingException` (or any `MessagingException`) does not apply.

Instead, the poll fails and the exception is thrown back to the poller.

If you want to handle exceptions in a polled endpoint (`MessageSource`), you need to give the poller an `ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor`, to which you can provide an `ErrorHandler` and do what you want with the exception, but since there is no message yet, it is the original exception thrown by the `MessageSource`.

If you want to send it to the error channel, you'll need to do that in your custom `ErrorHandler`.

Comment: Thanks Gary, certainly helps!